# How to add scroll to the current div after overflowing?

Tags: html, css

How to add scroll to a block element?

I've used `overflow-y: scroll`, but it immediately creates a scrollbar. I want scrolling after my `div` has reached a specific height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`overflow-y: auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y#auto) to get scroll after fulfilling the height of an element.

> `auto` Depends on the user agent. If content fits inside the padding box, it looks the same as visible, but still establishes a new block-formatting context. Desktop browsers provide scrollbars if content overflows. - MDN

> Whereas `scroll` Content is clipped if necessary to fit vertically in the padding box. Browsers display scrollbars whether or not any content is actually clipped. (This prevents scrollbars from appearing or disappearing when the content changes.) Printers may still print overflowing content. - MDN

Answer (score 0):

First you have to give a proper height and width of your content area where you have to overflow.
You have a `<div>` which has more content than your area than you can use overflow tag with scroll.....

```css
width: #;
height: #;
overflow: scroll;
```